# Android Studio does not render in Flutter Outline mode

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, flutter

Currently I am using Android Studio 3.2.1

Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338, built on October 9, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.13.0-46-generic

---

The Flutter Outline tool does not render the Widgets properly as given in this article [here](https://medium.com/flutter-io/flutter-outline-hot-reload-and-the-implementation-of-a-live-widget-preview-69abd39aa3bb).

[image: Flutter Outline display]
This is what I get. No widget displays any child in any case.

[image: Flutter Outline display 2]

None of the `Text` widgets are drawn.

Is this a bug or something wrong on my part or is the functionality only on IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 4):

Try this one. Click red restart button in dart anlysis tab.
[image]

Often, this results in success.